# .NET Number format - Separator on 2 digits

Tags: .net, vb.net

Number format not working as [expected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:##,##,##,###.####}", 12345678))

'Outputs 12,345,678
'Expected output 1,23,54,678 based on the format provided
```

How to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a specific culture (say India) you can specify that in the string formatter:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("gu-IN")
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(culture, "{0:##,##,##,###.####}", 12345678))
```

which will give you the output:

```
1,23,45,678
```

This is Gujarati. but the other Indian cultures ("hi-IN" for Hindi, "kn-IN" for Kannada, etc) work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the commas. Once you put a comma in the formatting string the formatter assumes comma on the periods (each 3 digits). If you escape all commas you don't trigger that behavior:

```
(123456789).ToString("##\\,##\\,##\\,###")
```

outputs

```
"12,34,56,789"
```

Comment: I think it should be just 1 slash. When I use two slashes, I see one in the output. Using one slash gives me the expected output.

Comment: @emaillenin That's because you have a `@` in front of your string, the code in the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
int input = 12345678;
Console.WriteLine(input.ToString(@"#\,##\,##\,###"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is expected, custom formatting strings are still subject to number formatting rules for the current culture.  Yours has a  NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes property that groups the digits by 3, very common.  Overriding the user's culture preference is in general a very bad idea, do think twice about it.  But you can create your own, use the NumberFormatInfo.Clone() method and modify the property:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var info = (NumberFormatInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        var groups = new int[] { 3, 2, 2 };
        info.NumberGroupSizes = groups;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(info, "{0:##,##,##,###.####}", 12345678));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: 1,23,45,678